# Adding BRAND image as header to a html page

Tags: html, css

[image]I am learning front end developement using html, css.
I want to create a menubar and above menu bar i need to add an image ( header image).

Problem is I am not getting the image which is added to my images folder.[image]

and this is the html code...
Kindly help me with the issue.
    enter code here

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

      <style>
         body{
            color:green;
         }
      </style>
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="/images/spmhead.jpg" scale="0" width="100%">
      </a>
  </div>
</nav>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hello World Mentors </a> 
    <div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Hell</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>

    </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
</div>

      <div class="container">

         <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Tutorials point</h1> 
            <p>Tutorials Point originated from the idea that there exists a class of readers who respond better to online content and prefer to learn new skills at their own pace from the comforts of their drawing rooms.</p> 
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">       
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
               <h2>Android</h2>
               <p>Android is an open source and Linux-based operating system for mobile devices such as smartphones and tablet computers. Android was developed by the Open Handset Alliance, led by Google, and other companies.</p>
         </div>
         <br>
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>CSS</h2>
            <p>Cascading Style Sheets, fondly referred to as CSS, is a simple design language intended to simplify the process of making web pages presentable.</p>
         </div>

         <div class="container">

         <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Java</h2>
            <marquee direction="up" scrolldelay=250 vspace=20 hspace=20 bgcolor=grey><p>Java is a high-level programming language originally developed by Sun Microsystems and released in 1995. Java runs on a variety of platforms, such as Windows, Mac OS, and the various versions of UNIX. This tutorial gives a complete understanding of Java.</p> </marquee>

         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <marquee direction="up">This text will scroll from bottom to up</marquee>
         </div>

     </div>
     </div>
         <div class="container">
         <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Tutorials point</h1> 
            <p>Tutorials Point originated from the idea that there exists a class of readers who respond better to online content and prefer to learn new skills at their own pace from the comforts of their drawing rooms.</p> 
         </div>
         <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Tutorials point</h1> 
            <p>Tutorials Point originated from the idea that there exists a class of readers who respond better to online content and prefer to learn new skills at their own pace from the comforts of their drawing rooms.</p> 
         </div>
      </div>
   <script src="js/jquery.js"> </script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>   
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whats the local URL you are using? If per chance it's something like localhost:80/learning/bootstrap.... And you are using a / at the start of your image path, then your image wont be loading, as it will be looking in the wrong directory. Maybe remove the leading slash from your image path.

Comment: Remove the leading `/` in your `/images/spmhead.jpg` path. Also, be mindful your HTML is invalid without a `title` element.

Comment: Start using developer tools, open console, check the path, etc...

Comment: I tried removing the / . it didnt work.   I am using bootstrap css files and  the path where my index.html desktop/learning/bootstrap/index.html       and the image stored is                       desktop/learning/bootstrap/images/spmhead.jpg

Comment: prepending '.' in /images /spmhead.jpg should make it work

Comment: If this is the `index.html` page you're working on, that should work. Make sure the file name is right and the extension is right (e.g. `jpeg` and not `jpg`).

Comment: what are the developer tools used..@Bojan Petkovski

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got solution for the question I have posted above.
This is the code which worked for me.

```
 <html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

      <style>
         body{
            color:green;
         }
      </style>
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>

<div class="container">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="images/spmhead.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </a>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hello World Mentors </a> 
    <div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Hell</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>

    </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
</div>

      <div class="container">

         <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Tutorials point</h1> 
            <p>Tutorials Point originated from the idea that there exists a class of readers who respond better to online content and prefer to learn new skills at their own pace from the comforts of their drawing rooms.</p> 
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">       
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
               <h2>Android</h2>
               <p>Android is an open source and Linux-based operating system for mobile devices such as smartphones and tablet computers. Android was developed by the Open Handset Alliance, led by Google, and other companies.</p>
         </div>
         <br>
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>CSS</h2>
            <p>Cascading Style Sheets, fondly referred to as CSS, is a simple design language intended to simplify the process of making web pages presentable.</p>
         </div>

         <div class="container">

         <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Java</h2>
            <marquee direction="up" scrolldelay=250 vspace=20 hspace=20 bgcolor=grey><p>Java is a high-level programming language originally developed by Sun Microsystems and released in 1995. Java runs on a variety of platforms, such as Windows, Mac OS, and the various versions of UNIX. This tutorial gives a complete understanding of Java.</p> </marquee>

         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <marquee direction="up">This text will scroll from bottom to up</marquee>
         </div>

     </div>
     </div>
         <div class="container">
         <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Tutorials point</h1> 
            <p>Tutorials Point originated from the idea that there exists a class of readers who respond better to online content and prefer to learn new skills at their own pace from the comforts of their drawing rooms.</p> 
         </div>
         <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Tutorials point</h1> 
            <p>Tutorials Point originated from the idea that there exists a class of readers who respond better to online content and prefer to learn new skills at their own pace from the comforts of their drawing rooms.</p> 
         </div>
      </div>
   <script src="js/jquery.js"> </script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>   
   </body>
</html>
```

[image: This is what i needed... Now can anybody help me to make the image of same size as the menu bar container]

Answer (score 1):

Refer the image tag with relative path .

```html
 <img src="./images/spmhead.jpg" scale="0" width="100%">
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be `<img src="images/spmhead.jpg" scale="0" width="100%">`.

Comment: After making all the changes mentioned here i am still getting the same issue. I have attached the screenshot of the output after making changes as mentioned by you all

Comment: did you already check the filename or the extension of the file? and can  u provide a screenshot of the console error on developer tools. (press f12).

Comment: I am using sublime text 2 editor. So I am not aware of any error msg. Ya the file name is .jpg in the images folder.